# I can't use DriverManager in a JDBC Java application

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm currently following a tutorial on jdbc, I've been following the steps however I'm stuck in this:
[image: a screenshot]

The IDE doesn't recognize `DriverManager`, it doesn't suggest any imports either. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you provide us more information? About your system, IDE, etc.

Comment: You need to import `java.sql.DriverManager`, and you have imported the wrong `Connection` class. If it doesn't suggest any imports, are you by any chance using a modular java project? That is, is there a `module-info.java`? If so, you either need to make your project non-modular by removing `module-info.java`, or you need to add `requires java.sql;` to the module definition in `module-info.java`.

Comment: i imported java.sql.Connection and java.sql.DriverManager , it works now . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Java Debug Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/) or `JDI` is different from [Java Database Connectivity](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/jdbc.htm#GSDVG00017) or `JDBC`.

You have imported the class, `Connection` from `JDI` API rather than `JDBC` API.

Address then following things in your code:

1. Import the classes from `java.sql` package as follows:

```
java.sql.Connection;
java.sql.DriverManager;
```

2. Note that `Class.forName()` is not needed since `JDBC 4.0`.

Comment: thanks. i imported the classes from java.sql and it worked

Answer (score 0):

you should import Connection class from `java.sql.Connection` instead of  `com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.Connection` because DriverManager class is in `java.sql.Connection` and `getConnection` method of DriverManager  return connection from `java.sql.Connection`

Comment: i imported java.sql.Connection, the Connection class does exist but DriverManager is still unrecognizable.

Comment: The OP also needs to import `java.sql.DriverManager`.

Comment: thanks i imported java.sql.DriverManager and it works now.